# custom drag able boxes, when to utilize them?

Tags: website-design, web-app, drag-n-drop

If anyone has used igoogle they would know that they can customize various boxes according to their choice. I was developing an web app and am really confused whether to give such an customization options to the user.

[image]

Well , am designing the Dashboard which would give their statistics and usage graphs etc. So should i make something like igoogle for customizing or in general when is the appropriate "situation" or scenario to use the same???

any incite would be helpful indeed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're building a platform, as opposed to a product, customization like this is a good idea.

Take your iGoogle example. Google's designers have stood back and said "I have no idea what kind of content is going to be important to you, or how it ought to be organized."

This is because you can load damn near anything into iGoogle. If your dashboard is similar, where users are picking a few items out of thousands, then I'd say absolutely.

If, on the other hand, your dashboard is just showing a few standard modules to everyone, then this kind of customization is probably not needed.

Comment: tnx for sharing your thoughts!! i would want to have others opinion before i completely agree with you. :)